# how to fix "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pikepdf'"

Tags: pdf, pyinstaller

The same problem continues to occur even though the pikepdf is already installed How do you solve it?

I reset the pip using 'python -mensurepip', and I had the same problem running powershell, gitbash as administrator

[installed pikepdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnlGX.jpg)

[but still...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9E6h.jpg)